# MySQL find records using between

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, between

Here my code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `products`
WHERE
DATE_ADD( UTC_TIMESTAMP( ) , INTERVAL 7 HOUR ) 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB( STR_TO_DATE( IsPromotionDate,  '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i' ) , INTERVAL 3 DAY ) 
AND STR_TO_DATE( IsPromotionDate,  '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i' )
```

But the results return all the products that before IsPromotionDate but not after IsPromotionDate - 3. I still haven't figure it out why.

Comment: out of curiosity and to discard any easy issue, would you mind giving us an extract of `select IsPromotionDate from products`  please?

Comment: What are the data in the table, post your table data and expected result and result you got.

Comment: Thank you. Here my sreenshot http://imgur.com/2aqbmRz

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM  `products`
WHERE DATE_ADD(UTC_TIMESTAMP( ), INTERVAL 7 HOUR) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(IsPromotionDate, INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND IsPromotionDate
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM  `products`
WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR), IsPromotionDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `products`
WHERE
STR_TO_DATE( IsPromotionDate,  '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')
BETWEEN NOW()
AND  DATE_SUB( now() , INTERVAL 3 DAY )
```